# Logical switch with redstone

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-mods

I'm playing Enigmatica 2 Expert and I wanted to make an automated battery charger using my fission reactor. I wanted to make charge cycles between 30 and 80% for efficiency sake. I can output a 0 or a 1 whenever the battery gets either below 30% or above 80%, and I have a simple input that turns the charger on and off.

My idea was to make a switch that turns on when battery goes below 30% (first line is on) and turns off only when the battery is above 80% (second line turns on), but the problem is that I don't know how this switch is called and if it can be made with redstone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation I found out that I needed what's called a RS Latch, which can be made with a simple design using two pistons facing each other and moving a redstone block from the two different inputs. More designs can be found in the MC wiki under Memory Circuits.